# minimalistic python service layer

Tags: python, mysql, json, rest

I plan to have mysql/postgres database along with a thin service layer which I basically would like to us to receive restful requests and return results in json format. I'd like to use python for latter. Since I am new to python frameworks, if I'd use any for this thin layer which one would that be? The more minimalistic (thinner) the better of course.

Thanks for sharing your experience.

Juergen

PS: If it dealt with authentication/auhorization that would be a bonus.

Comment: A late comment on what I finally chose: django and tastypie. Admittedly not minimalistic however easy to implement and well documented.

Answer (score 1):

Flask is one of the python Microframework. 
It support session.
very lean and easy to build new stuff.

http://flask.pocoo.org/

Pyramid (former name was Pylons) is also good candidate to build simple web service with RESTful.

Good thing about pyramid is you can expand it from very small scale to large scale easily.
pyramid also support authentication and session and bunch of template engine or ORM.

http://www.pylonsproject.org/

If u consider expanding your project later, I suggest using Pyramid.

Comment: Hmm. @Bittrance You are right about that. Flask doesn't support authentication by itself. I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at pyramid and web2py and let you know about my experience with them.

Answer (score 0):

For very simple things I am always using bottle. But if you need a little bit more than that (like auth), consider using [web2py](http://www.web2py.com). It does all you need with very little coding.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at pyramid and web2py and let you know about my experience with them.